# Cakephp Helper fire Error on certain view

Tags: cakephp, helper, php

I got something strange with my helper.
First of all, i just started to work with cakePHP, and MVC. 
Maybe i do somethings wrong but can't find what.

For my app, i have to use an Xml file to handle language for my texte (i know there are many differents way to handle language, but i need to use this one).
So i create an Helper (XmlHelper.php, in View\Helper\Xmlhelper.php)

```
<?php
App::uses('AppHelper', 'View/Helper','Xml');


class XmlHelper extends AppHelper {
    var $xml = array();
    var $name = 'Xml';
    var $filename = '';

    public function getXml($filename, $language, $view) {
         $this->xml = Xml::toArray(Xml::build('Xml/'.$filename.'.xml')); //THE LINE
         $this->xml = $this->xml[$filename][$language][$view];
         $this->filename = $filename;
    }

    public function readXml($tags) {
        $tempXml =  $this->xml;
        foreach ($tags as $tag){
            $tempXml =  $tempXml[$tag];
        }
        return  $tempXml;
    }
}
```

From my controller i got :

```
class EventsController extends Controller {
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form','Xml');
    public $components = array('Session');
```

And for most of my view everything work fine, but some other just fire

```
Error: Class 'Xml' not found File:
C:\wamp\www\cakephp\app\View\Helper\Xmlhelper.php Line: 11
```

In my view i call :

```
<?php $this->Xml->getXml('dico',$ln,'thanks'); ?>
<h1><?php echo $this->Xml->readXml(array('texte'));?></h1>
```

The ln is well defined.

If someone can explain me what is wrong, it will be very apreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the XML class you're using *inside* your XmlHelper.

Basically, you're using `App:uses();` wrong, it can only be used to include one class at a time, so you need to add another line:

```
App::uses('AppHelper', 'View/Helper');
App::uses('Xml', 'Path/To/Xml.php');
```

I can't really help you with the `Path/To/Xml.php` bit as I don't know where you've saved it. Should really be in the Vendors folders if it's an external library. [See here for more info](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-classes).

Comment: Nice job, it's effectivly that, i have to use :
App::uses('Xml', 'Utility');
Thanks a lot